# Correct Demonstration?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $$\frac{a}{(a,b)}\mid c \;\ \Rightarrow \;\ a\mid b\cdot c$$
$$\frac{a}{(a,b)}\mid c\Rightarrow c=\frac{a}{(a,b)}\cdot k\Rightarrow b\cdot c=\frac{a \cdot b}{(a,b)}\cdot k\Rightarrow b\cdot c=a(\frac{b}{(a,b)}\cdot k)\Rightarrow$$$$a\mid b\cdot c$$
**This is correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$a|bc\iff \exists k\in\mathbb Z,\ bc=ka\iff \exists k\in\mathbb Z,\ \frac{b}{(a,b)}c=k\frac{a}{(a,b)}$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ and since $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ are coprime then $\frac{a}{(a,b)}|c$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ $\frac{a}{(a,b)}|c\iff\exists k'\in\mathbb Z,\ c=k'\frac{a}{(a,b)}\Rightarrow \frac{b}{(a,b)}c=\underbrace{\frac{b}{(a,b)}k'}_{=k}\frac{a}{(a,b)}$

Comment: that $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ are relatively prime, I get ($(\frac{a}{(a,b)},\frac{b}{(a,b)})=1$), but did not understand why they concluded directly $\frac{a}{(a,b)} \mid c$ Could you explain again with more details?

Comment: This result is known as the Euclid lemma: if $a|bc$ and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then $a|c$.

Comment: But I understand that $\frac{a}{a(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ are relatively primes, but $a$ and $b$  what too relatively primes?

Comment: No in your problem $a$ and $b$ aren't relatively prime.

Comment: So why use the motto that says
$$a \mid b \cdot c \Rightarrow a \mid c \;\;\ \text{If a and b coprime}$$
Since we have $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ are coprime, and the requirement of the lemma is that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: In the lemma $a$ and $b$ and $c$ aren't the same numbers as in your problem, let's change the notation: this lemma says: if $p|qr$ and $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime then $p|r$ and of course to apply this in your problem: replace $p$ by $\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $q$ by $\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ and $r$ by $c$.